# official support of MongoDB in django

Tags: python, django, database, mongodb, nosql

I want to use the `MongoDB` database in `Django`.

Officially there are no `Django-MongoDB` drivers available. I found some third-party sources, but they're outdated. I found some projects on `GitHub`, but they are also outdated (last updated 2-3 year ago).

What are my option? Is there any official support for `MongoDB` in `Django`?

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html) looks like best solution at this point.

You need to install `django@nonrel` and `djangotoolbox` so non-relational db can work properly on your django project.

After installing `mongodb-engine` just activate it in `settings.py` file